# Is it possible to right-align a tab using the jQuery easytabs plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to accomplish this and while I can get a tab to appear on the right-hand side of the tab container using absolute positioning, when the tab is active the container content jumps up by a few pixels.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56z7ommp/), and here's some code:

`<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
      <ul class='etabs'>
        <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1">Left</a></li>
        <li class='tab' style="position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;">
          <a href="#tabs4">Right</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="panel-container">
        <div id="tabs1">
          <h2>This panels tab should be left-aligned...</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs4">
          <h2>This panels tab should be right-aligned...</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`

```
.etabs { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    position: relative;
}
.tab { 
    display: inline-block; 
    zoom:1; 
    *display:inline; 
    background: #eee; 
    border: solid 1px #999; 
    border-bottom: none; 
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
}
.tab a { 
    font-size: 14px; 
    line-height: 2em; 
    display: block; 
    padding: 0 10px; 
    outline: none; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tab.active { 
    background: #fff; 
    padding-top: 6px; 
    position: relative; top: 1px; 
    border-color: #666; 
}
.tab a.active { 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
.tab-container .panel-container { 
    background: #fff; 
    border: solid #666 1px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; 
}
```

The plugin is initialized with `$('#tab-container).easytabs()`.

Comment: here's a little update: http://jsfiddle.net/56z7ommp/1/ do you know enough css to do the rest?

Comment: Apparently not. I haven't been able to resolve that gap under the tabs. Either the left will have it or the right will have it.